# GRUB: Possible to use bluetooth keyboard + mouse?

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

So when my computer boots GRUB pops up and I can pick between Ubuntu (first) and Windows 11.

Is it possible to use my bluetooth keyboard? I have a bluetooth USB adapter attached to the back of my motherboard.

My assumption is that know this won't work. I have a USB-C cable I can attach the keyboard with but was just checking if this was possible.